# Cannot use YouTrack with nginx on a subdomain

Tags: nginx, youtrack

I am trying to run YouTrack as a subdomain via nginx. But YouTrack does not work.

I am using YouTrack 2018.1.41826, since the update to YouTrack 2019 did not work (no login possible after update, but this is a separate issue), nginx 1.18.0, Java 8u265-b01 for YouTrack and (AdoptOpenJDK-)Java 11.0.8+10 for nginx and for tomcat (see below). I start YouTrack on port 8081 via

`java -Xmx2048m -jar youtrack-2018.1.41826.jar localhost:8081 &`

Inside YouTrack, the base URL is configured to be `https://<my domain>/youtrack`, `<my domain>` being my domain name. On port 8080, a tomcat server is running with different applications. So I configured nginx as follows (replace `<my domain>`):

```
    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        client_max_body_size 12m;
        client_body_buffer_size 16k;

        sendfile        on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

        location / {

            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_read_timeout  90;

            proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://<my domain>;
        }

        location ~ ^/youtrack/(.*)$ {

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffers 8 64k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;

            client_max_body_size 10m;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/$1;

            proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8081 https://<my domain>/youtrack;
        }

        location ~ ^/youtrack/api/eventSourceBus/(.*)$ {
            proxy_cache off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_set_header Connection '';
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/eventSourceBus/$1;

            proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8081 https://<my domain>/youtrack;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
```

Now, when opening https:///youtrack/ in the web browser, the URL changes to `https://<my domain>/oauth?state=%2F`, forgetting about the `youtrack` subdomain. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered on youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-58725 (it is actually simpler):

```
location /youtrack {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_buffers 8 64k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;

            client_max_body_size 10m;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/youtrack;
            proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8081 https://<my domain>;
}

location /youtrack/api/eventSourceBus {
            proxy_cache off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_set_header Connection '';
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/youtrack/api/eventSourceBus;
            proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8081 https://<my domain>;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental limitation with YouTrack is that it should be deployed with the same URL path you'd like to proxy it with.

For example, to make it work on `https://<my domain>/youtrack` one should deploy the application to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/youtack`, not just to `http://127.0.0.1:8081`.   So the application start command is to be adjusted as follows:

`java -Xmx2048m -jar youtrack-2018.1.41826.jar 8081/youtrack`

Also, don't forget to update `proxy_pass` directives in the Nginx config file accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, starting YouTrack with `8081/youtrack`, and using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/youtrack/$1;` and `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/youtrack/api/eventSourceBus/$1;` in the nginx configuration, when I then call  a non-existing page, e.g. `https://<my domain>/youtrack/nix`, the URL stays the same and I get a beautiful error page that the page does not exist. But when calling `https://<my domain>/youtrack/` the page gets redirected to `https://<my domain>/youtrack/oauth?state=%2Fyoutrack%2F` where nothing is displayed.